# working with PartialRendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MachinesManagement";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MachineList", "MachinesManagement", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "grd" }))
{

<div id="filterDiv">
@{Html.RenderPartial("/Views/MachinesManagement/MachineFilter.cshtml");}
</div>
<div id="grd">
@{Html.RenderPartial("/Views/MachinesManagement/MachineList.cshtml");}
</div>
}
```

`

When i try to run the Application I am getting following error

"The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'KCMSWebClient.MachineManagementService.NtegraSearchCriteria'."

can any help.???
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very clear. You need to pass an instance of the `KCMSWebClient.MachineManagementService.NtegraSearchCriteria` class to your partial. This could be done using the second argument of the `RenderPartial` helper:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial(
    "/Views/MachinesManagement/MachineFilter.cshtml", 
    PASS_AN_INSTANCE_OF_THE_REQUIRED_CLASS_HERE
);}
```

If you don't use this second argument, the `RenderPartial` method simply passes the current view model (`@Model`). And since I cannot see any `@model` directive on the top of your Razor page, I assume that your view is not strongly typed to any model and when you served this view from the controller action you didn't pass any model to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I have change my code to this also..

`@{Html.RenderPartial("/Views/MachinesManagement/MachineFilter.cshtml", new KCMSWebClient.MachineManagementService.NtegraSearchCriteria());}`


but on next view error is "Object reference not set to instance"

Comment: Why do you need to use a `ViewBag`? I would recommend you to avoid using it. Your partial is already strongly typed to a model. Simply pass whatever information you need as a property of this model.

Comment: You set a property of the model that you are passing to your view. Currently you have only done `new KCMSWebClient.MachineManagementService.NtegraSearchCriteria()` but you have to pass a real instance with properties assigned.

Comment: Well, then you will have to adapt your code so that it uses a view model instead of your domain `NtegraSearchCriteria` entity. In this view model you could include whatever properties your partial view requires.

Comment: In my case in viewbag i have a data which is not an part of model. Its different list

Comment: That's the whole point of my comment: use view models then which will be adapted to the requirements of your view so that you don't need any ViewBag.